# SwiftUI JSON decoder throws empty data

Tags: json, swift, jsondecoder

I'm learning SwiftUI in XCode and I'm stuck with this problem with some strange conditions, I'm using two iPhones for debug, one of them is an iPhone XS where I can't find a solution to fix it, the only way to solve it is modify some code on my project and then rebuild it, but one day after the error comes again.

This is the code I'm using:

```
func loadJSON<T: Decodable>(_ filename: String) -> T {
let data: Data

guard let file = URL(string: filename)
    else {
        fatalError("Couldn't find \(filename).")
}

do {
    data = try Data(contentsOf: file)
}
catch {
    //fatalError("Couldn't load \(filename):\n\(error)")
    data = Data.init() //if I remove this, the exception comes from this line ▲
}

do {
    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    return try decoder.decode(T.self, from: data)
}
catch {
    fatalError("Couldn't parse \(filename) as \(T.self):\n\(error)") //<- error comes here
}
}
```

And this is the debug output:

```
Thread 2: Fatal error: Couldn't parse http://**myURL** as Array<ItemClass>:
dataCorrupted(Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "The given data was not valid JSON.", underlyingError: Optional(Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Unable to parse empty data." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Unable to parse empty data.})))
```

And in the other iPhone (is an iPhone 8) this problem does not happen, both of them have the same version of iOS and the same Development profile installed.

Comment: `data` is empty some times.  You should keep `fatalError("Couldn't load \(filename):\n\(error)")`, or at least a `print` and share the `error` thrown. it might tell you why `Data(contentsOf:)` fails, and why you call `Data.init()`.

Comment: The error *"The given data was not valid JSON."* is quite clear. The file doesn't contain (valid) JSON.

Comment: @vadian the JSON is perfectly valid, just in this moment I tried to open the app and the error came back, then I modified the code to remove the `Data.init()` just like @Larme suggested and now the app is loading the JSON with no problem but tomorrow the app will crash again. As I just wrote in the beginning, I'm new in Swift but I'm pretty familiarized with JS, C# and PHP and I'm struggling understanding how Swift works, but this situation is very strange and happens only in one iPhone.

Comment: Your syntax with regard to the error handling is confusing. Use **one** `do - catch` block and in the `catch` scope write `fatalError("An error occurred:  \(error)"`. The whole error object will tell you what's wrong and where the error is related to.